# How to find ellipses in text string Python?

Tags: python, regex

Fairly new to Python (And Stack Overflow!) here. I have a data set with subject line data (text strings) that I am working on building a bag of words model with. I'm creating  new variables that flags a 0 or 1 for various possible scenarios, but I'm stuck trying to identify where there is an ellipsis ("...") in the text. Here's where I'm starting from:

```
Data_Frame['Elipses'] = Data_Frame.Subject_Line.str.match('(\w+)\.{2,}(.+)')
```

Inputting ('...') doesn't work for obvious reasons, but the above RegEx code was suggested--still not working. Also tried this:

```
Data_Frame['Elipses'] = Data_Frame.Subject_Line.str.match('.\.\.\')
```

No dice.

The above code shell works for other variables I've created, but I'm also having trouble creating a 0-1 output instead of True/False (would be an 'as.numeric' argument in R.) Any help here would also be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: It is just 3 full stops (`...`) or a proper ellipsis (`…`). Can you give an example of a Subject_Line?

Comment: It looks like the escape character is in the wrong position. The backslash should come before the period.

Comment: Here's a sample subject line:

"<First Name>, psst…it’s time for a new _product name_"

Comment: There may be cases where it is 3 full stops and a proper ellipsis. In that case I'd like to use an or statement in my RegEx to capture both scenarios.

Comment: I don't know what lib you are using but why not `"if "..." in Data_Frame['Elipses']"`?

Comment: Try `str.search(r'(\w+)\.{3,}')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `search()` instead of `match()` would spot an ellipses at any point in the text. In Pandas `str.contains()` supports regular expressions:

For example in Pandas:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Text' : ["hello..", "again... this", "is......a test",  "Real ellipses… here", "...not here"]})
df['Ellipses'] = df.Text.str.contains(r'\w+(\.{3,})|…')

print(df)
```

Giving you:

```
                  Text  Ellipses
0              hello..     False
1        again... this      True
2       is......a test      True
3  Real ellipses… here      True
4          ...not here     False
```

Or without pandas:

```py
import re

for test in ["hello..", "again... this", "is......a test",  "Real ellipses… here", "...not here"]:
    print(int(bool(re.search(r'\w+(\.{3,})|…', test))))
```

This matches on the middle tests giving:

```
0
1
1
1
0
```

Take a look at [search-vs-match](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match) for a good explanation in the Python docs.

---

To display the matching words:

```
import re
    
for test in ["hello..", "again... this", "is......a test",  "...def"]:
    ellipses = re.search(r'(\w+)\.{3,}', test)
    
    if ellipses:
        print(ellipses.group(1))
```

Giving you:

```
again
is
```

Comment: That seems to be much closer. Here's the code I adapted from your answer:

`Data_Frame['Ellipsis'] = re.search(r'(\w+)\.{3,}', str(Data_Frame.Subject_Line))`

I had to convert the data set to string in this case for some reason, even though it's already a string. The output, however, is this in every instance of the data in the CSV output:

`<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(280, 284), match='s...'>`

Which looks like it's matching (searching) but finding a match in every instance. Does this look correct? Also is there a way to make the output 0/1 ?

Comment: It's difficult to say without seeing your source text. Do the line lengths make sense? e.g. `print len(str(Data_Frame.Subject_Line)))` ?   Converting to `bool()` and then `int()` would give you a `0` or `1` return.